# How can I achieve this functionality to enter DOB in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

[image]

I used a variable to store the text being entered and modifying it by appending the remaining suffix of "mm/dd/yyyy". I am getting the functionality, but if I try to update the cursor to the right position, its creating a problem.
I used the textfield.selectedTextRange to move the cursor from EOF to position I need. But, it is replacing the text entered with last "y" from "mm/dd/yyyy". So If I enter "12" the text changes from mm/dd/yyyy| to "yy|/mm/yyyy" instead of "12|/dd/yyy"

Am I doing it the wrong way?

```
let dobPlaceholderText = "mm/dd/yyyy"
var enteredDOBText = ""

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField){
    enteredDOBText.append(textField.text.last ?? Character(""))
    let modifiedText = enteredDOBText + dobPlaceholderText.suffix(dobPlaceholderText.count - enteredDOBText.count)
    textField.text = modifiedText
    setCursorPosition(input: dob.textField, position: enteredDOBText.count)
}
private func setCursorPosition(input: UITextField, position: Int){
    let position = input.position(from: input.beginningOfDocument, offset: position)!
    input.selectedTextRange = input.textRange(from: position, to: position)
}
```

Comment: We do not know if you are doing it wrong because you did not show what you are doing. Please show actual code. Much better than merely talking about it.

Comment: Sorry @matt. The gif was not uploaded immediately. Now it is. Please check

Comment: So https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield would not be better?

Comment: @matt I can update the text and modify cursor only after the text entry is completed. So cannot use the `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`

Comment: Inside `shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString` you can get the updated text like this: `let updatedString = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)`

Comment: @aheze the issue I am having trouble with is updating the cursor location and I believe I cannot do it in `shouldChangeCharatersIn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion of matt and aheze in the comments to use `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` is very promising in such use cases.

The procedure could look something like this:

- determine the resulting text as it would look like after the user input and filter out all non-numeric characters
- apply the pattern as defined in your `dobPlaceholderText`
- set the result in the UIText field
- determine and set new cursor position

In source code it could look like this:

```
let dobPlaceholderText = "mm/dd/yyyy"
let delims = "/"
let validInput = "0123456789"

func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
               shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let filteredText = filtered(textField.text, range: range, replacement: string)
    let newText = applyPattern(filteredText, pattern: Array(dobPlaceholderText))
    textField.text = newText
    let newPosition = newCursorPosition(range: range, replacement: string, newText: newText)
    setCursorPosition(input: textField, position: newPosition)
    return false
}
```

The actual implementation of the three methods `filtered`, `applyPattern` and `newCursorPosition` depends on the exact detail behavior you want to achieve. This is just a sample implementation, use something that reflects your requirements.

```
private func filtered(_ text: String?,range:NSRange, replacement: String) -> Array<Character> {
    let textFieldText: NSString = (text ?? "") as NSString
    let textAfterUpdate = textFieldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: replacement)
    var filtered = Array(textAfterUpdate.filter(validInput.contains))
    if filtered.count >= dobPlaceholderText.count {
        filtered = Array(filtered[0..<dobPlaceholderText.count])
    }
    return filtered
}

private func applyPattern(_ filtered: Array<Character>, pattern: Array<Character>) -> String {
    var result = pattern
    var iter = filtered.makeIterator()
    
    for i in 0..<pattern.count {
        if delims.contains(pattern[i]) {
            result[i] = pattern[i]
        } else if let ch = iter.next() {
            result[i] = ch
        } else {
            result[i] = pattern[i]
        }
    }
    return String(result)
}

private func newCursorPosition(range: NSRange, replacement: String, newText: String) -> Int {
    var newPos = 0
    if replacement.isEmpty {
        newPos = range.location
    }
    else {
        newPos = min(range.location + range.length + 1, dobPlaceholderText.count)
        if newPos < dobPlaceholderText.count && delims.contains(Array(newText)[newPos]) {
            newPos += 1
        }
    }
    return newPos
}
```

**Demo**

[image: demo]